# How to properly use/configure YT gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, youtube, rubygems, youtube-api

I'm trying to reproduce this tutorial : [YouTube API, Version 3 on Rails](https://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-api-version-3-rails/)
 in order to apply it on my own project. But I'm having a hard with it since few days.

At first, I had this error :

> A request to YouTube API caused an unexpected server error: To display
>   more verbose errors, change the configuration of Yt with: Yt.configure
>   do |config| config.log_level = :debug end

I updated RVM and Ruby and I'm getting this error now :

> Yt::Errors::Forbidden in VideosController#create A request to YouTube
>   API was considered forbidden by the server: To display more verbose
>   errors, change the configuration of Yt with: Yt.configure do |config|
>   config.log_level = :debug end

I already :

- get ruby and rvm updated
- tried different version of the yt gem
- tried that : OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
- tried that : config.force_ssl = false

this

curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=wuZfOIWwM_Y&part=snippet"

return that :

[image: curl result]

Using Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.3.0;
Source code at : https://github.com/NeimadTL/YT_Sample_App

Any help, suggestions would be strongly and sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> [forbidden](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) (403)  forbidden   Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.

**Answer:** The request you are making is not authorized.  update: Change key= to access_token=

**Possible cause:**

```
https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?key=
```

You are trying to run a request `annotations_invideo` (*which I cant actually find any were in the documentation*) and you are applying an API key to it.  API keys only work with public data.  Either `annotations_invideo` is not a valid request to the API or its something that you need to be authenticated for.   If you need to be authenticated then you will need an access token and then apply `access_token=` instead of `key=`

where exactly did you find annotations_invideo ?

Update:

Lucky for me it has been under an hour since you posted your question I was able to take

```
https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?access_token=AIzaSyBSvIOM0EGX1tcrf5IAlYJuH_ttqVgTO4Q&video_id=BPNYv0vd78A
```

and dump it in a web browser it returned data.

```
<document>
<annotations>
<annotation author="" id="annotation_1585555999" log_data="ei=B2k9WIOCB8X0dNKokKAG&a-id=annotation_1585555999&xble=1&a-type=4&a-v=BPNYv0vd78A" style="title" type="text">
<TEXT>Hello, world!</TEXT>
<segment>
<movingRegion type="rect">
<rectRegion d="0" h="25.2779998779" t="0:00.000" w="75.0" x="13.1540002823" y="67.3239974976"/>
<rectRegion d="0" h="25.2779998779" t="0:02.089" w="75.0" x="13.1540002823" y="67.3239974976"/>
</movingRegion>
</segment>
<appearance bgAlpha="0.25" bgColor="0" borderAlpha="0.10000000149" effects="" fgColor="16777215" fontWeight="bold" highlightFontColor="16777215" textSize="21.6642"/>
</annotation>
<annotation id="channel:563d3ce4-0000-20cc-8fd5-001a11463304" style="playlist" type="promotion" log_data="ei=B2k9WIOCB8X0dNKokKAG&a-type=12&a-ch=UCwCnUcLcb9-eSrHa_RQGkQQ&xble=1&a-id=563d3ce4-0000-20cc-8fd5-001a11463304&l-class=2&link-id=PLuW4g7xujBWfU26JUTW1DGs3hk4LD5KaL&a-v=BPNYv0vd78A">
<data>
{"playlist_length":"200","session_data":{"itct":"CAIQwTcY____________ASITCMOh497wzdACFUU6HQodUhQEZCj4HTICaXZIwN_33vSX1vkE","annotation_id":"563d3ce4-0000-20cc-8fd5-001a11463304","feature":"iv","ei":"B2k9WIOCB8X0dNKokKAG","src_vid":"BPNYv0vd78A"},"is_mobile":false,"text_line_2":"Adorable Kids","text_line_1":"Check this playlist","image_url":"https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/yDrLVqRHAsw\/mqdefault.jpg","start_ms":1000,"collapse_delay_ms":86400000,"end_ms":3000}
</data>
<segment/>
<action trigger="click" type="openUrl">
<url type="hyperlink" target="new" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDrLVqRHAsw&list=PLuW4g7xujBWfU26JUTW1DGs3hk4LD5KaL"/>
</action>
</annotation>
</annotations>
</document>
```

Note: I wonder why this is returning XML and not Json it has me thinking this is an older api.  Found it you are using the YouTube API v2 which is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience) It should have been shut down .

https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2014/09/have-you-migrated-to-data-api-v3-yet.html

you should drop this and move to the [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Comment: the curl command was a the suggestion in the error message at one point. This gem has been created specifically to handle the YouTube API V3 according to the tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-api-version-3-rails/). Thank you for your help. I'll try to get in touch with the author of this gem.

Comment: I updated my post with the curl result for YT API V3.